# Doubts about box shadow (Am I doing it right?)

Tags: html, css

That's all what I could do (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DntW.png)

My teacher wants me to create this kind of shadow, but I didn't find any solution to create something like this, I do not know if she is crazy and It's not possible, but It isn't possible with just the element "box-shadow" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqOfz.png)

Comment: Please include your code in the question, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, create a pseudo element `::after` on that red bordered box, then give it also a box-shadow with a blur, a transparent background, and either position it absolute to the red box or give it a margin-top and margin-left.

Not giving you a finished example here, since your teacher wants you to learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use an online box shadow creator. There are many out there, like this one: https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Here is a sample using that box shadow generator.

```css
#box{
  padding:20px;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:40px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">test</div>
```